# Open a Dialog on ListView item click

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I want to open a `Dialog` every time I click on a `ListView` item.

This code is not working and I really cant find error. Please help!

```
 private void loadFeed(){
            try{
                BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
                messages = parser.parse();
                List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
                for (Message msg : messages){
                     descriptions.add(msg.getDescription());
                    titles.add(msg.getTitle() + "\n" +msg.getDate());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
                this.setListAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Throwable t){
                Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView descriptions, 
                    View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(descriptions, v, position, id);
            String description = descriptions.get(position);
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.single);
                dialog.setTitle("Blog");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                text.setText(description);
                dialog.show();

        }
```

with this code the app is running ,the dialog show the description but the description is also shown in the list item.

```
messages = parser.parse();
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
for (Message msg : messages){
    titles.add(msg.getTitle() + "\n" +msg.getDate() + "\n\n" + msg.getDescription());
 }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row2)
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SinglePost);
            text.setText(selection);
            dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: @kotas: Wrong, Means what problem you are facing, can you pls tell me, whether you had got any issues in Logcat or not

Comment: eclipse doesnt let the program run..it highlight with red line the get in    String description = descriptions.get(position); and says to add cast to descriptions(i tried it but that forces down my app)

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work because the method `get(int i)` does not exist for the type `ListView` nor for the `ArrayAdapter`.

**EDIT:**

You seem to confound the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) class and the [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) interface. Those are two totally different things!

A class implementing the `List` interface like the `ArrayList` in your case holds objects and a `ListView` class is and Android widget which displays `View`s in a list representation.

I really recommend you working through the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) tutorial section so you get a basic understanding of the Android views before diving into more complex stuff.

Comment: is there any way to fix it please?

Comment: if i change in the onListItemClick (ListView l,...) and then super.onListItemClick(l,...) it highlights the descriptions and prompts me to create local variable..

Comment: It would help if you would tell us what you try to achieve with that get method.

Comment: ok.i m getting rss feed from a web site. in my listView i would like to appear the title and the date and then ,when the user clicks on this list item,to open a dialog with the description.so,i thought to create a second list(descriptions) and then call it in the dialog..hope thats understandable

Answer (score 0):

i'm doing something like that ... and it helps me to much. I't's not mine so please give the credit whom it deserves.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467140/how-to-open-dialog-from-listview
```